# C# AcessExceptionViolation with Marshal.Copy

Tags: c#, c++, struct, vb6

I'm translating a program from VB to C# which communicates with an external program MMTTY.EXE. This program has ActiveX controls for VB6.0 and I added to my C# project in Visual Studio 2013.

The code in VB is this:

```
Dim m_nmmr(63) As Long
Private Sub XMMR_OnNotifyNMMR(pNMMR As Long)
Call CopyMemory(m_nmmr(0), pNMMR, 64 * 4)   'Windows API CopyMemory()*
```

This event is produced when MMTTY.EXE have data and the data pointed by pNMMR is copied in m_nmmr(63) buffer.

The program in C# that I made is this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory")]
    static extern void CopyMemory(Int32[] Destination, IntPtr Source, uint Length);
private void XMMR_OnNotifyNMMR(object sender,      AxXMMTLib._DXMMREvents_OnNotifyNMMREvent e)
    {            
        IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)e.pNMMR;
        Int32[] m_nmmr = new Int32[63];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, m_nmmr, 0, 63);
    }*
```

But when I execute it I get an AccessViolationException. It tells me that there is an attempt of writing or reading in a protected memory.

How can I solve this problem? any idea?

This is the help of the original method for VB6.0:

void OnNotifyNMMR(long* pNMMR)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  This event is generated at the timing of TXM_LEVLEL message arrival.  NMMR struct pointed by pNMMR is defined by

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    DWORD   m_markfreq;
    DWORD   m_spacefreq;
    DWORD   m_siglevel;
    DWORD   m_sqlevel;
    DWORD   m_codeswitch;
    DWORD   m_codeview;
    DWORD   m_notch1;
    DWORD   m_notch2;
    DWORD   m_baud;
    DWORD   m_fig;
    DWORD   m_radiofreq;
    DWORD   m_Reserved[53];
}NMMR;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

the application does not have to respond all the XMMR events if it uses this struct.  Because NMMR struct simply consists of LONG variables, it can be copied to VB Long array.  The index of the array has several names, such as xr_markfreq, in XMMT.ocx.  For details, refer to Predefined constants of XMMR.

```
[Example]
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Dim m_nmmr(63) As Long

Private Sub XMMR_OnNotifyNMMR(pNMMR As Long)
    Call CopyMemory(m_nmmr(0), pNMMR, 64 * 4)   'Windows API CopyMemory()
    |
    MarkFreq = m_nmmr(xr_markfreq)
    SpaceFreq = m_nmmr(xr_spacefreq)
       |
    'Pass pNMMR to the control for the supplemental control
    Call XMMSpec.UpdateByNMMR(pNMMR)    'Update the frequency property of XMMSpec control
    Call XMMLvl.DrawByNMMR(pNMMR)   'Draw the level indicator
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++?

Comment: Because the definition of NMMR structure is made in C++ , or am I wrong?

Comment: Have you checked to determine if the inbound event object (to your new event handler) contains a valid pointer value in e.pNMMR?

Comment: It has the value of 1519 , which is the value of xr_markfreq in the program mmtty.exe , What is a valid value for a pointer?

Comment: The XMMR_OnNotifyNMMR() method signature is pretty fishy, its arguments are a complete mismatch with the VB6 version.  Pretty hard to see how that could have happened, my crystal ball says that there's a delegate involved that we can't see.

Comment: Consider that the `DWORD` type is an unsigned 4-byte integer. You´re trying to map the data to an array of `Int32` which is signed... of course, this can´t be the cause for the `AccessViolationException`; just mentioning...

Comment: You don´t need the import of the `RtlMoveMemory` function in `C#`; use functions of the `Marshal` class to manipulate and work with unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 0):

The 63 is the Problem:

In VB6, 63 is to top index (0..63).

in C#, 63 is the COUNT of elements (0..62).

So you miss 4 Bytes. You can simple check this with a small console program, breakpoint at first assignment:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] test = new int[1];
        test[0] = 1;
        test[1] = 2; // <- this will crash
    }
```